# How to Programmatically Create Video Template (from barchart racer to kpop line count)

Tags: animation, after-effects-scripting, programming

I have seen tutorials on how to generate barchart racer animations programmatically using languages like Python, once you script it, next time, you just need to load the load and the animation will got generated easily. However, the animation quality is skill mediocre.

Recently I came across a style of visualizing line distributions (how many lines certain celebrities said) in Youtube videos like this. The video quality is absolutely stunning and you can clearly see a consistent theme across all the videos under that channel ([click to watch the video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxYXvWDDcd8)).
[image]

I am wondering what are the alternatives to achieve "Kpop line distribution" level of video editing in a programmatically.

As I have mentioned, previously, I have tried generate photos using Python and stich them together and exported as video, I have also used d3.js and even Processing but none of these solutions look as a clean cut.